# Correct way to introduce if statement to specific for loop?

Tags: javascript

**EDIT: Just to clarify, as zer00ne spotted this was originally minified code that I "beautified" in order to modify it. Apologies for not making that clear sooner.**

Original for loop, that works:

```
m = 0;
for (k = b.header.length; m < k; m++) d.appendChild(p(e, "col", {
  attr: {
        min: m + 1,
        max: m + 1,
        width: N(b, m),
        customWidth: 1
  }
}));
```

What I want to do, but doesn't work:

```
m = 0;
for (k = b.header.length; m < k; m++) d.appendChild(p(e, "col", {
  if (m==6) {
    attr: {
        min: m + 1,
        max: m + 1,
        width: 100,
        style: 2,
        customWidth: 1
    }
  } else {
    attr: {
        min: m + 1,
        max: m + 1,
        width: N(b, m),
        customWidth: 1
    }
  }
}));
```

I understand that the if statement is in the wrong place w.r.t. the function d.appendChild,  but I'm not sure how to separate the for loop from the function in order to place the if statement  in the correct position. Finally what is this style of for loop/function hybridisation called?

Help?

Comment: *"Finally what is this style of for loop/function hybridisation called"* – It's called "a maintenance nightmare". Stick to what most style guides recommend and write `for (...) { d... }`, with appropriate line breaks and indentation. It should then become more obvious where to put the `if` statement too.

Comment: There is no hybrid here

Comment: Hybridwuh? Did you just take a piece of minified code and beautify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about `for` loop, it's about possibility to use `if` inside object literal. In short, there's none.

What you might do instead is *extend* a specific param based on condition, like this:

```
var m = 0;
var attr;
for (var k = b.header.length; m < k; m++) {
  attr = {
    min: m + 1,
    max: m + 1,
    customWidth: 1
  };
  if (m === 6) {
    attr.style = 2;
    attr.width = 100;
  }
  else {
    attr.width = N(b, m);
  }
  d.appendChild(p(e, 'col', { attr: attr }));
}
```

This approach is DRY: the attributes common for both cases are specified once (so it's easier to modify them).

Have you worked with just a single varied param, there would have been another way to do this - with ternary:

```
attr = {
  min: m + 1,
  max: m + 1,
  width: m === 6 ? 100 : N(b, m),
  customWidth: 1
};
```

---

Still, there's another thing to consider: what's `6`? It's not clear to any reader - including you several months (or even weeks, depending on the codebase's size) later.

Comment: it's code to generate the xml for an excel file. '6', in this case, refers to a specific column.

Answer (score 1):

Open the for loop, then put the if inside, and put appendChild in the if statement:

```
for (<stuff>) {
    if (<expression>) {
        d.appendChild(<stuff>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put the if-condition as parameters into d.appendChild. That won't work:

```
m = 0;
for (k = b.header.length; m < k; m++) {
   if (m==6) {
      d.appendChild(p(e, "col", {
        attr: {
           min: m + 1,
           max: m + 1,
           width: 100,
           style: 2,
           customWidth: 1
        }
      }));
   } else {
      d.appendChild(p(e, "col", {
         attr: {
            min: m + 1,
            max: m + 1,
            width: N(b, m),
            customWidth: 1
         }
      }));
   }
}
```